# Deprecated method when making c2d com from azure IotHub to python script

Tags: python, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

```
message = client.receive_message()
```

This code is now deprecated and when searching for a solution it seems I am the only one with this issue.
I get this warning:

> DeprecatedWarning: receive_message is deprecated as of 2.3.0. We
> recommend that you use the .on_message_received property to set a
> handler instead of message = client.receive_message()

If you have a possible solution, please post it here.
I am running the latest python 3.9 and the latest Azure IoT device library.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a method that's no longer supported (because it's deprecated). As the error message says, the correct way to handle C2D messages is to use an event handler. There is a good example of that [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios/receive_message.py)

The part you will be interested in is:

```py
  # define behavior for receiving a message
  # NOTE: this could be a function or a coroutine
  def message_received_handler(message):
      print("the data in the message received was ")
      print(message.data)
      print("custom properties are")
      print(message.custom_properties)
      print("content Type: {0}".format(message.content_type))
      print("")

  # set the mesage received handler on the client
  device_client.on_message_received = message_received_handler
```